# воспроизведение нескольких аудио на странице с остановкой уже запущенных

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, аудио

На странице есть несколько тегов аудио и кнопок прикрепленных за ними:

```js
function onplayssoun(snd) {

  $('audio').stop(); //Останавливаем все аудио
  var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
  audio.src = snd; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
  audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
  var audio = $('audio')[0];
  $(document).click(function() {
    audio.play();
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audio0" src="sound0.mp3"></audio>
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="onplayssoun('sound0.mp3');">

<audio id="audio1" src="sound1.mp3"></audio>
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="onplayssoun('sound1.mp3');">
```

И при воспроизведении второй мелодии по счету - воспроизведенная до этого не останавливается, а продолжает играть, при этом обе мелодии накладываются одна на другую. Мне надо что бы при воспроизведении мелодии если была воспроизведена какая то мелодия до этого она останавливалась. Что я написал тут не так? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: у тебя уже есть `<audio>` тег, на кой ты и в функции создаешь новый объект  `new audio`?

Comment: @Air то есть надо не создавать объект и без него сразу запускать или удалять каждый раз старый объект? как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuralim, тег `<audio>` в основном можно и надо использовать 
когда хочешь простой штатный аудио плеер использовать, если визуально штатный плеер на странице не нужен, можно просто создать объект `new audio()` и запускать звук так, как в данных примерах.

```js
var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    audio.src = this.value;
    audio.play();
    console.log(this.value)
  })

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?">
<input type="button" value="http://ic7.101.ru:8000/v3_1?userid=0&setst=qa472mjc0lh95pk1tj8d3319g6&city=0">
```

Ну вот еще вариант на `jquery`

```js
var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio

$('input').click(function() {
  audio.src = this.name
  audio.play();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Радио Шансон" name="http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?">
<input type="button" value="АвтоРадио" name="http://ic7.101.ru:8000/v3_1?userid=0&setst=qa472mjc0lh95pk1tj8d3319g6&city=0">
```

Comment: Посмотри, тут пример без `JQ` на чистом `js`, ну логику ты точно поймешь, я в `JQ` не силен и им не пользуюсь, любою чистый `js`

Comment: Ну вот самому стало интересно и сделал пример на `JQ`))))

Comment: Зачем подписываться на каждый инпут, когда можно на всплытие события? И ещё можно дата-атрибуты использовать для адреса.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну у него было на каждый `input`, вот по этому и такой пример привел, что было проще человеку понять, а какой ему атрибут использовать думаю сам решит, тем более что у меня в разных примерах по разному реализовано, не мне же за него весь код писать, тем более когда не знаю, что и как  там именно он хочет творить...

Comment: Везде у тебя одинаково реализовано.